# how to avoid n+1 query in realmResults?

Tags: android, realm

```
lateinit var outletResults: RealmResults<Outlet>

outletResults = Outlet.search(query)

val areas = outletResults.map { outlet -> outlet.area }.distinct()

for (area in areas) { 
   var outlets = outletResults.where().equalTo("area", area).findAll().sort("name")
   ....
   ....
}
```

i want to get the outlet per area based on outletResult, how do i achieve this without looping the query ?

Comment: Have you tried distinct over the link to area ID? I don't remember if that's supported or not.